# Tomcat service stop responding after windows gone to sleep mode

Tags: java, windows, tomcat7

I have long polling Ajax which is waiting on thread . Once windows go to sleep mode that Ajax request canceled automatically and tomcat stop responding for other request .

Comment: be more specific...and why sleep mode active on "server" machine?

Comment: The easy answer would be to configure your Windows to stop sleeping.  I can tell you that when my work laptop in the office goes into sleep mode it can no longer be accessed over the network.  This is normal behavior.

Comment: i am using it as a local server for desktop application.